# Pex ignores [PexAssumeNotNull] and PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pex

I have the following PexMethod:

```cs
[PexMethod]
public bool fwAlertConfig_objectConfigExists(
    [PexAssumeUnderTest]WinCC target,
    [PexAssumeNotNull] List<mixed> alertConfigObject,
    [PexAssumeNotNull] ref int configType,
    [PexAssumeNotNull] ref List<string> exceptionInfo
)
{
    PexAssume.TrueForAll(alertConfigObject, x => x.value != null);
    PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull(alertConfigObject);
    bool result
       = target.fwAlertConfig_objectConfigExists(alertConfigObject, ref configType, ref exceptionInfo);
    return result;

}
```

I deliberately placed the `[PexAssumeNotNull]` and `PexAssume` there. However,
it seems that these things are ignored when I "Run Pex explorations" these are the inputs created: 
[image: PexResults]

Please notice the following:

- `in exceptionInfo` is `null` in every line, although it has `[PexAssumeNotNull]`
- line 2: alertConfigObject is `{null}`, although I defined `PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull(alertConfigObject)`
- line 4: `new mixed` has `{value=null}`, although I defined 
  `PexAssume.TrueForAll(alertConfigObject, x => x.value != null)`

However: `[PexAssumeNotNull]` works well for alertConfigObject, as I do not see null as an input anymore.
So why are the other assumptions not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't test it, because you didn't provide the code under test, but you can try to replace the `[PexAssumeNotNull]` attribute with the static method `PexAssume.IsNotNull`, like this:

```
   [PexMethod]
   public bool fwAlertConfig_objectConfigExists(
       WinCC target,
       List<mixed> alertConfigObject,
       ref int configType,
       ref List<string> exceptionInfo)
   {
       PexAssume.IsNotNull(target);
       PexAssume.IsNotNull(alertConfigObject);
       PexAssume.IsNotNull(configType);
       PexAssume.IsNotNull(exceptionInfo);

       PexAssume.TrueForAll(alertConfigObject, x => x.value != null);
       PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull(alertConfigObject);
       bool result
          = target.fwAlertConfig_objectConfigExists(alertConfigObject, ref configType, ref exceptionInfo);
       return result;
   }
```